# Unable to sync gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I get error messages when I try to add recyclerview and cardview dependencies to my build.gradle.  Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.truewebdev.applytheme"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.cardview-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

Here are the error messages:
[image: error1]
If I try to install repository, I get the following:
[image: error2]

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the Android Support Repository from the SDK Manager?

From android docs:

> Make sure you have downloaded the Android Support Repository using the SDK Manager.

http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res